# Keep comments in preprocessor i file

Tags: comments, preprocessor, keil, preprocessor-directive

We want to use the preprocessor output file (`.i` file ) for further use, especially the comments.
For that, we use the `/PREPRINT` (or `/PP`) command line switch.
The problem is that the KEIL compiler (C166) deletes any comments.

**Q:** Is it possible to keep comments in the `.i` file?

**Additional research:**
The Microsoft compiler does this with the `/P` command line switch.
But they has `/C` to *keep* comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out that the C166 Keil compiler supports also the `/C` compiler switch. This switch is not available through the IDE and is not documented.
To use it, we had to write a batch file that contains the `/C` switch and run the compiler a second time to create the `.i` file.

It also turns out that all of the compilers we use has this switch (Mircosoft, and as Arun Taylor mentioned, the GCC compiler). So we are able to use the commented `.i` file from every compiler.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
gcc -E -CC file.c
```

It keeps all the comments, including the ones in the .h files that may have been included by C file.

Comment: Good to know for the GNU compiler, which we have also in use! But I was searching for the same thing on the Keil compiler.